# Correct way to bind numeric values to prepared sql

Tags: c++, c, postgresql

I haven't been working with libpq-fe, (postgresql-9.1.3)

```
PGresult * pg_res;
char * sql = "INSERT INTO tbGroups (Group_UID, Full_Name, User_UID) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);";
int group_uid = 11;
int user_uid = 1;
const char * name = "TEST1";
const char * values[3] = {(const char *) &group_uid, name, (const char *) &user_uid};
int lengths[3] = {sizeof(group_uid), strlen(name), sizeof(user_uid)};
int format[3] = {1, 1, 1};

pg_res = PQprepare(conn, "insert_tbgroups", sql, 3, NULL);
PQclear(pg_res);

pg_res = PQexecPrepared(conn, "insert_tbgroups", 3, values, lengths, format, 1);
PQclear(pg_res);
```

Works, but result is:

```
rcpdv=# select group_uid, full_name, user_uid from tbGroups;
 group_uid |   full_name   | user_uid 
-----------+---------------+----------
 184549376 | TEST1         | 16777216
(1 rows)
```

What is correct way to bind numeric values to prepared sql, without param_types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL is expecting the data to come across a network connection. So you have to convert your numerical data into network format (big endian). I typically use `ntohl()` functions, for a crude example in your case:

```
int format[3] = {1, 1, 1};

for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    format[i] = ntohl(format[i]);
}
```